# Post array of objects with AngularJS $http

Tags: json, angularjs, http, post

I am making an app where a user can submit multiple links to a form. The links are then stored in an array of objects before posting them to my backend. But somehow my JSON structure turns up like this in ExpressJS:

```
[
  '{"title":"link1","url":"url1"}',
  '{"title":"link2","url":"url2"}'
]
```

This is my angularJS:

```
$scope.saved_link = [];

  $scope.uploadLink = function(title,url) {
    $scope.saved_link.push({
      title : title,
      url : url
    });
  }

  $scope.onSubmit = function(pubForm, url) {
    var file = $scope.upload_file;
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);

    $http.post(url,fd, {
      transformRequest: angular.identity,
      headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
      params: {
        links: $scope.saved_link,
        image: file.name
      }
    }).then(function successCallBack(response){
    })
  }
```

Any one know how to get rid of those quotation marks?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Content-Type must be set for fixing the format.

`Content-Type: application/json`

Ref:
[AngularJS $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Alternatively,

you can try to parse the string into an object at the backend.

Ref:
[JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)